# How to make the Routing with react in a finished Build work?

Tags: java, reactjs, build, routes, installation

i repolish my portfolio with the new technology "react", but i have a problem with the production build. I use for my routing the BrowserRouting in react. When i call it in development it works great, but when i set up the build with npm run build and deploy it, the links are broken. 
I have done several steps to make the links work again but nothing worked.
Someone has experience with the routing and deploying? Tried to modify the .htaccess to rewrite the routing for the index.html file, but yeah..

here is my set Up partly:

App.js

```
  <FadeIn><React.Fragment>
  <Router exact path=".">
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/vita" component={Vita}/>
      <Route path="/references" component={References}/>
      <Route path="/demoreels" component={DemoReels}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</React.Fragment></FadeIn>
```

header.js

```
      <div className="Linkbar"> 
          <a href='/about'>About</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/vita">vita </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/references">references </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a href="/demoreels">demo reels </a>
        </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: what's the access link/url that points to this build/app? you can add dummy words, just want to see the path pattern

Comment: and where it is deployed?

Comment: it is deployed on a Linux Server which i ordered. The access link is my host/domain. www.mydomain.de/abtou, etc..

Comment: Are you able to root page? `/`

Comment: Yes, only links didn`t work. If i click the links the 404 error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `.htaccess` to map all urls to `index.html`

This might help
https://www.andreasreiterer.at/fix-browserrouter-on-apache/

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: do you have read my question?^^ tried the same thing with the same webside, but unfortunately it doesn`t work. Do i have to consider something to make the .htaccess work?